# Merge sorted lists

Tags: linux, unix, sorting

I have a few .txt files (in the same directory) that look like this:

```
   123 carrot
    50 apple
    13 tomato
     5 potato
     2 pear
```

and

```
   100 carrot
    10 apple
     3 tomato
     2 potato
```

I need to merge them into one sorted list. So if I only had two lists above, I'd get

```
   223 carrot
    60 apple
    16 tomato
     7 potato
     2 pear
```

Is there an easy way to do this with shell commands, or should I start writing code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where is the line between "shell commands" and "code"? This example is perhaps beyond that line, but it is just a quick aggregation function in `awk` that I already had written for another (more elaborate) purpose, so I might as well post it.

Assuming the files are located in the directory `dir/`, `awk` could sum them as such:

```
awk '
    {fruits[$2]+=$1}
    END { for (fruit in fruits) {printf "%6s %s\n", fruits[fruit], fruit} }
' dir/* | sort -rn
```

Breakdown:

- Check every line in all files and add the value of the first field to the existing value of the index of that fruit in the array `fruits` (or create that index if it does not exist).
- When the files have been traversed, loop over the indices in `fruits` and print their value and their name in your specified format.
- Array sorting in `awk` is possible, but it's a lot easier on the eye to just use `sort`. `-rn` sorts numerically in descending order.